# Getting duplicates while parsing json array in oracle

Tags: json, oracle

We have following Json structure stored in a CLOB field Payload from table TB_PAYLOAD :-

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "orderItems":[
            {
            ...
                "associations":[
                    {
                        "type":"Product"
                        "id":"xyz"
                        ..
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"ProductOrderItem"
                        "id":"KBCDDD"
                        ..
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"ABCD"
                        "id":"123abc"
                        ..
                    }
                    ....
                ]
            },
            {
             ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

We have Multiple orderItems and each orderItems has multiple associations.
We are trying to get data from association.id when association.type = **"Product"** or **"ProductOrderItem"**. which will populate 2 different Columns.

For example for above Json file we would like the result to be :-

```
PRODUCT_ID            xyz
PRODUCTORDERITEM_ID   KBCDDD
```

we have tried below query but it results in duplicates since we have multiple orderItems which result in cross join :-

```
SELECT O.ENTITY_ID , CASE WHEN T.TYPE_1 IS NOT NULL THEN T.PRD_ID_1 END AS PRODUCT,
CASE WHEN T2.TYPE_2 IS NOT NULL THEN T2.PRD_ID_2 END AS PRODUCTORDERITEM
FROM 
(
SELECT 
ENTITY_ID , PAYLOAD
FROM TB_PAYLOAD  
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
)
o
 LEFT JOIN json_table(o.PAYLOAD, '$.data.orderItems[*].associations[*]' 
         columns (
               prd_id_1  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.id',
               type_1  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.type'
         )
     ) t
on t.type_1 in ('Product')
 LEFT JOIN json_table(o.PAYLOAD, '$.data.orderItems[*].associations[*]' 
         columns (
               prd_id_2  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.id',
               type_2  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.type'
         )
     ) t2
on t2.type_2 in ('ProductOrderItem')
;
```

We want to know if we can get the solution without using PL/SQL.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See NESTED_PATH syntax, e.g. https://blogs.oracle.com/jsondb/the-new-sqljson-query-operators-part5:-jsontable,-nested-path,-ordinality-column

Comment: @Padders I know nested path , but I dont know how would it help me with solution